# Advantage of RMI over API Interface on 2 apps on same java virtual machine

Tags: java, interface

I´m currently working on an analysis of an abstraction layer with different interfaces. Can you guys tell me what are the advantages of using a RMI interface to change data with another java application running on the same Java Virtual Machine over using a REST or SOAP API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RMI use native Java serialization so it's more efficient than XML or JSON serialization in CPU and memory and size. And RMI don't deal with http stack.

REST and SOAP are interesting for interoperability with other technologies and to communicate over the web, it passes usually through firewall thanks to HTTP stack.

So in local machine in the same JVM RMI outperfom REST and SOAP.

I don't know if there are specifics optimization of RMI if client and server run on the same JVM.